# Git recover undoed changes?

Tags: git, visual-studio

I just made a huge mistake and undoed two days of work in Git. Don't know how it happened but I must have pressed "Undo changes" instead of "Stage" in Visual Studio. Jeessus. I must be tired. It could also be a major bug in the Git-integration but I doubt it. Is there any way to get it back? Any cache somewhere with local changes? Does VS keep some kind of local history?

Comment: Two days of work without committing once? Ouch.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution that worked now. Luckily I had compiled the latest version before undoing and not recompiled again, so I was able to recover the code via ILSpy! Phew. Lesson learned I hope.